# Widget area in WordPress theme

Tags: php, css, wordpress, widget, sidebar

I've a theme that i converted from HTML into WP everything work nice but sidebar is not in it place! showing Widgets in the down!

Widgets are ok and in the right place in single.php but in index.php and page.php are not.

I already tried with style.css file but still not solved. what do you think? what should I do?

http://s14.postimg.org/ul2401b4h/Fire_Shot_Screen_Capture_004_robert_s_Blog.png

Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide specific code where sidebar was called "get_sidebar" in index.php and page.php ?

Comment: in index.php   <?php get_sidebar(); ?>      \     in sidebar.php   <div id="sidebar">
 <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'primary' ); ?>
</div>

Comment: There's something wrong in the structure of html and css, you must check it again or give us more code to check for you

Comment: What code do you need? I'll give you. (from what file)